# can i use IndicBERT for question answering system

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, nlp-question-answering, fine-tuning, kannada

i want to build a question answering system in kannada language. the context is set for BMTC bus routes, the user asks a question "from kempegowda bus stand i want to go to Jallahalli cross, what are the buses i can take to get there?" answer "you can take 250B 258AB 258B". the question and the answer are in kannada itself, i am writing in english for understanding purpose. How can i go about this, i have looked and found out the indicBERT can be used, from AI4bharat. is there any other models that i can use which can be easier to do?

if there are other models that i can use and hopefully be easier to use, i havent found any codes related to indicBERT or how to train and how to use it.